# Spliting std::string and a character array into two halves (efficiently)

Tags: c++, c, string

How can we split a `std::string` and a **null terminated character array** into two halves such that both have same length?

Please suggest an efficient method for the same.You may assume that the length of the original string/array is always an even number.

By efficiently I mean using less number of bytes in both the cases, since something using loops and buffer is not what I am looking for.

Comment: "By efficiently I mean using less number of bytes in both the cases, since something using loops and buffer is not what I am looking for".  How do you propose to store those new strings?  When you split them, your final result must have at least one more byte in order to store the additional null terminator, which means you need to reallocate, which means you must copy an array of bytes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've already received a C++ answer, but here's a C answer:

```
int len = strlen(strA);
char *strB = malloc(len/2+1);
strncpy(strB, strA+len/2, len/2+1);
strA[len/2] = '\0';
```

Obviously, this uses `malloc()` to allocate memory for the second string, which you will have to `free()` at some point.

Answer (score 6):

```
    std::string s = "string_split_example";
    std::string half = s.substr(0, s.length()/2);
    std::string otherHalf = s.substr(s.length()/2);

    cout << s.length() << " : " << s << endl;
    cout << half.length()  << " : " << half << endl;
    cout << otherHalf .length()  << " : " << otherHalf  << endl;
```

Output:

```
20 : string_split_example
10 : string_spl
10 : it_example
```

Online Demo : http://www.ideone.com/fmYrO

Comment: what about a character array?

Comment: @Tretwick Marian: convert character array into `std::string`, and then do the split!